# Twilio - to call from verified caller id to PSTN no

Tags: android, twilio

I am wondering, if multiple verified caller ids could make call to any PSTN.

I have seen the server.py on github using a single no as TO no for client to PSTN,but is it possible to make a calls instead of the fixed verified caller id ?

Comment: Twilio supports multiple caller IDs. You can verify any number (eg: Your cellphone number) and set it as the caller ID when making calls with your twilio account.

Comment: @AkhilBalakrishnan here is the php code for making call  `$client->account->calls->create($from,$to, "http://xxxxxxxxxxx/calling?frommobileno=%2B$from_plus_removd&mobileno=%2B$to_plus_removd", array(`

Comment: You can substitute any verified number in place of $from. Refer this link to know how to verify a number. https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-do-i-add-a-verified-outgoing-caller-id-with-twilio

Comment: No. If you are making calls to PSTN, you have to set a caller ID number. Either a twilio number, or a number verified with twilio.

Comment: @AkhilBalakrishnan can you please give php code of connect($to,$from) method ? for better understanding,if you have done it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
Do you want to initiate a call from a number to a PSTN number?

Comment: yes i want to make call from any verified caller id to PSTN no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98334/discussion-between-yogesh-seralia-and-akhil-balakrishnan).

Comment: Please try my answer first.

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer by ticking on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You have to verify a number (Say +911234568794) by following the instructions given [here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-do-i-add-a-verified-outgoing-caller-id-with-twilio).

Then download the twilio helper library for php. Then try the following code.

```
require_once {Path to twilio library/}.'twilio.php';
function initiateOutboundCall($from, $to){
 $sid = "{{your sid}}"; 
 $token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
 $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
 $call = $client->account->calls->create($from, $to, TWILIO_HANDLE_URL, array(
        "Timeout" => "30",
        "Method" => "GET",
        "StatusCallback" => TWILIO_STATUS_CALLBACK_URL
    ));
return $call;
}

$from = "+911234568794"; //Your verified number
$to = "TO NUMBER HERE";
$call = initiateOutboundCall($from, $to);
```

Comment: please tell me what should be the response of TWILIO_HANDLE_URL method and TWILIO_STATUS_CALLBACK_URL

Comment: It is optional. Twilio will make a request to this URL after the call is disconnected. You can specify other events also. Like ringing, connected etc.  You can do logging etc in this URL.

Comment: i had made this response of TWILIO_HANDLE_URL `<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+91xxxxxxxxxx">
        <Client>"+91xxxxxxxxxx"</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>`  is it correct ?

Comment: If want to dial a client, it should be like "<Client>Registered_clientname</Client>"

Comment: and for dialing a PSTN no ?

Comment: <Dial>
        <Number>YOUR_NUM_HERE</Number>
   </Dial>

Please note that you have to enable international dialing from twilio admin panel to make calls to Indian numbers,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98340/discussion-between-yogesh-seralia-and-akhil-balakrishnan).